# Де поставити крапку: перед закриттям лапок чи після них?

Tags: пунктуація

Пряму мову пишемо в лапках. А де поставити крапку чи знак оклику в кінці такого речення: перед закритими лапками чи після них? Адже у Вікіпедії такого пояснення немає.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Але чинний — 2015 року (точніше: 2012 року) — правопис пояснює.

Не тільки про пряму мову:

[§ 124. Лапки](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par124)

> **Примітка 3.**
>
> а) Кома, крапка з комою, двокрапка й тире ніколи не ставляться перед закритими лапками, а тільки після них.
>
> б) Знак питання, знак оклику й крапки ставляться або перед закритими лапками, якщо вони відносяться лише до слів, поставлених у лапках, або після лапок, якщо ці розділові знаки стосуються всього речення.
>
> **Примітка 4.**
>
> Якщо знак питання, знак оклику й крапки стоять перед закритими лапками, то після лапок ті самі знаки не повторюються; неоднакові ж знаки можуть, залежно від змісту, ставитися одночасно й перед закритими лапками, й після них:
>
> > *Чи знайомі ви з романом Герцена «Хто винен?»*
> >
> > Але: *Невже ти не чув, як кликали: «До зброї, товариші!»?*

Про пряму мову детальніше в наступному §, там подібне ствердження:

[§ 124. Розділові знаки при прямій мові](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil5.htm#par125)

> **2.** Коли пряма мова йде в рядок, без абзацу, то перед початком її ставимо відкриті лапки, а в кінці — закриті лапки й *відповідний до характеру речення розділовий знак*:
>
> > *У цей час я побачила далеко машину і стала показувати в інший бік: «Дивіться, дивіться! Хтось іде!»* (Яновський).

Answer (score 2):

• Коли пряма мова в лапках, то знак оклику, питальний знак та трикрапка ставляться всередині лапок:

> Дивуюсь, радію, у серця питаю: «Скажи, віще серце, чи скоро світ буде?» /П. Куліш/

• Коли пряма мова закінчує речення (стоїть наприкінці речення) і в ній є крапка, то крапку ставимо поза лапками:

• А коли пряма мова на початку чи в середині речення, і наче там крапку треба поставити, а далі йдуть слова автора, то крапку всередині лапок не ставимо, а ставимо після лапок кому та довге тире «—» перед словами автора:

> «Хто творить розумну і добру людину — найкращий майстер», — таке було рішення стариків.

Знак питання, знак оклику й крапка ставляться або перед закритими лапками, якщо вони відносяться лише до слів, поставлених у лапках, або після лапок, якщо ці розділові знаки стосуються всього речення. 
Якщо знак питання, знак оклику й крапки стоять перед закритими лапками, то після лапок ті самі знаки не повторюються; неоднакові ж знаки можуть, залежно від змісту, ставитися одночасно й перед закритими лапками, й після них.

Посилання: [один](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/136.html), [два](http://shkolyar.in.ua/pryama-mova5), [три](http://forum.slovopedia.com/viewtopic.php?t=515).